# Is it a good idea to use !Important in a CSS file

Tags: css

I have lots of CSS files on my current project, and a lot of the styles in these files have !important besides them.  A feeling inside me tells me that this is not a good thing.  Can someone shed some light on what happens when we use !important and whether it is a good idea or not.

thanks,

Sachin

Comment: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!important` gives a style precedence and will ensure (where it can) that it is the style used. If you are using `!important` because your selectors just aren't specific, or well thought out, enough, then that's not the way they should be used. For me, there more useful for when you may have to deal with styles you have no control over.

To illustrate, where you might want to use `!important, you might have two stylesheets. One 'global' , that you have control over and one 'local', that you do.

In the global stylesheet, you might have the following:

```
p span {
    color: black;
}
```

In the local one, you could override this by doing:

```
p span {
    color: red;
}
```

This might work, but if the local one is included before the global one, there will be a conflict and the global styles will take precedence. To overcome this, you can do:

```
color: red!important;
```

In the case where you could just be more specific with your selectors, it would be better to do that, rather than use `!important`.

Global, all spans are black:

```
span {
    color: black;
}
```

In local, spans inside paragraphs are red:

```
p span {
    color: red;
}
```

There's nothing 'wrong' with using `!important` really, I guess it's a case by case scenario, but hopefully the above explains how to make the best use of them.

Some more discussion on '[When using !important is the right choice](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)' over on CSS tricks.

Comment: I guess if you were able to be more specific by saying that spans with a certain class should be red then that would be best of all.

Comment: Indeed, the more control you have over the HTML the more control you can potentially have in the CSS. Similarly, the more control you can hand over the CSS by being more specific with selectors, the better as you may be able to target common items without bloating your code with classes if they're not needed.

Answer (score 4):

`!important` means the rule cannot be overridden.  Take note that user stylesheets using `!important` will override author stylesheets.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules

Whether this is bad or good really depends on the usage.  I don't use this keyword often myself.  One example is that it allows me to override styles pulled in from 3rd party widgets/plugins.

Comment: It can be overridden, but only by a more specific `!important` declaration targeting the same elements. [See example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuDS8/).

Comment: I guess that means that by using it one is circumventing the normal cascading operation of CSS?

Comment: What's the difference between an author and a user stylesheet?

Comment: A user stylesheet resides on the user's computer allowing them to override the styles of web pages they are viewing.  A user may want to do this if they prefer fonts to be larger and always have links underlined etc.  The author stylesheet would be stylesheet served with the webpage.